# How to get full changelog from Git as an artifact in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, changelog, teamcity-8.0

I wonder, are there any way to get full changelog for the project as an artifact in TeamCity.

So I want it to look something like this:

```
Build 1.0.0:
- Commit 1
- Commit 2
Built 1.0.1:
- Commit 3
```

Are there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an artifact, probably it is not possible yet.

But you can use Teamcity's [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) to achieve something similar:

- Get all/some builds of a project (use **/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=buildType:[buildtypeid]**).
- For each build, geta list of change logs
  log (use **/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:[build id]**).
- For each change log, get change log details (use **/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:[change id]**).
- Form the data above to the format you desire.

Also you can always check the "Change Log" tab on your build result, but it requires you to parse the html page to get the format you want.

[image]

Comment: Why is it so diffcult in 2020? :(